# convert json to pojo using jquery/spring/jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

```
$.ajax({
  cache:false,
  type: 'POST',
  url: "${saveDTO}",
  data: mySubmitData, //a stringified json object, a form converted using toObject plugin
  contentType: "application/json",
  success:  function(data) {            
    savedDialog.html( JSON.stringify(data) + "<br><br>"+mySubmitData);
  }
});
```

and the controller is :

```
public @ResponseBody MyDTO saveDTO(@Valid final MyDTO myDTO,BindingResult result, Model model){
 System.out.println(myDTO.getMyField + "  " + myDTO.getSecondField;
 return new MyDTO();
}
```

The output I get in dialog shows this :

```
{"myField":null,"secondField":null} //new empty dto converted and returned spring

{"myField":"RU","secondField":"13-02-12"} //submitted data, a form converted to json
```

Whilst my sys out console output shows both fields are null, the json has not bound !!! Why ? The DTO itself just has two private fields with appropriate getters/setters

Comment: Add the code for `MyDTO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//js
var mySubmitData ='{"myField":"myFieldValue", "secondField":"secondFieldValue"}';
//dto
public class MyDTO implements Serializable {

  private String myField;

  private String secondField;

  MyDTO() {} //important

  public void setMyField() { ...}

  public void setSecondField() { ... }
}
//web resource
    public @ResponseBody MyDTO saveDTO(@Valid final MyDTO myDTO,BindingResult result, Model model){
     System.out.println(myDTO.getMyField + "  " + myDTO.getSecondField;
      return  myDTO;
      //return new MyDTO(); //it's empy object if you don't have default values
    }
```

Comment: Nice try, you kinda missed the key point. myDTO fields are null, the sys out print command pritns out null. I am a retuning a new object to check the correct mappings. I think the problem is in my serializer/deserializer